# Create UDP client socket without socket listening

Tags: sockets, udp, listen

I'm using the standard way, shown in many examples, to create a UDP socket in C++, keep it alive and keep sending stuff over it.

I only call `sendto`. I never call `recvfrom`. In this code fragment I only use `sendto` once and then sleep for 5 seconds:

**C code:**

```
static int do_the_rest( int sock )
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    bzero(&server_addr,sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("192.168.32.32");
    server_addr.sin_port=htons(32000);

    char sendline[100];
    bzero(sendline,sizeof(sendline));

    const struct sockaddr * addr = (const struct sockaddr*)&server_addr;

    sendto(sock,sendline,sizeof(sendline),0,addr,sizeof(server_addr));

    sleep( 5 );

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int sock;

    sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
    if( sock < 0 ) {
        perror( "socket" );
        return 1;
    }

    int ret = do_the_rest( sock );
    close( sock );

    return ret;
}
```

Now, if I run "netstat -na", I can identify that the system seems to listen on the local port of the socket (I remove the lines in my program that print the local port, for clarity):

**netstat -na:**

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
...
udp        0    304 0.0.0.0:53735               0.0.0.0:*
```

When I try something similar in Java, I also seem to get some listening, although it looks a bit different (perhaps IPv6?):

**Java code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Udp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        DatagramSocket sock = new DatagramSocket(null);

        try {
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.32.32");

            byte[] sendData = new byte[50000];

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                sendData, sendData.length, ipAddress, 32000);

            sock.send(sendPacket);

            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } finally {

            sock.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**netstat -na:**

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
...
udp        0      0 :::37053                    :::*
```

I understand this is done in order to support a possible `recvfrom` (`receive` in Java) that may follow. However, is there a way to tell the socket not to listen to incoming packets at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, if I run "netstat -na", I can identify that the system seems to listen on the local port of the socket

UDP sockets have a kernel buffer for incoming messages. This buffer is maintained by the kernel regardless whether you call `recv/recvfrom/recvmsg` from user-space code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shutdown()` with its `how` parameter set to `SHUT_RD` to disable reads on the socket, which may have the intended behavior of stopping the listening, maybe even freeing the kernel's receive buffer.  But the receive port has to remain allocated for the socket's lifetime, as it is used as the source port for the outgoing packets you are sending with `sendto()`.  You cannot avoid that.

Comment: Thank you, although the shutdown() did not help. I think it may only have effect on TCP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only 'listening' on that port, it is *sending* via that port. The port allocation is required. The socket gets bound to a port as soon as you call sendto(), unless it is already bound.